# How to programmatically get the Spark Job ID of a running Spark Task?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

In Spark we can get the Spark Application ID inside the Task programmatically using:

```
SparkEnv.get.blockManager.conf.getAppId
```

and we can get the Stage ID and Task Attempt ID of the running Task using:

```
TaskContext.get.stageId
TaskContext.get.taskAttemptId
```

Is there any way to get the Spark Job Id that is associated with a running Task (preferably using TaskContext or SparkEnv)?

Comment: You can get the "stage_id()" of the Task, if that helps.

Comment: why do you want this?  (I"m curious).

Comment: I have Spark SQL UDFs (implemented as Scala methods) in which I want to get the details of the Spark SQL query that called the UDF, especially a unique query ID, which in SparkSQL is the Spark Job ID. That's why I wanted a way to detect the Job ID from the UDF code itself when it is executed on the Executors as Tasks.

A logic in my UDF requires this unique query id (Job ID) to enforce that the UDF execution(s) will be consistent for each SparkSQL query.

Answer (score -2):

Spark has a lot of [monitoring built in](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) and analysis possibility after the fact.

Spark does have a [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api). That you can programically interact with.

If you prefer you can recieve metrics in a sink:

> Spark’s metrics are decoupled into different instances corresponding
> to Spark components. Within each instance, you can configure a set of
> sinks to which metrics are reported. The following instances are
> currently supported:
>
> master: The Spark standalone master process. applications: A component
> within the master which reports on various applications. worker: A
> Spark standalone worker process. executor: A Spark executor. driver:
> The Spark driver process (the process in which your SparkContext is
> created). shuffleService: The Spark shuffle service.
> applicationMaster: The Spark ApplicationMaster when running on YARN.
> mesos_cluster: The Spark cluster scheduler when running on Mesos. Each
> instance can report to zero or more sinks. Sinks are contained in the
> org.apache.spark.metrics.sink package:
>
> ConsoleSink: Logs metrics information to the console. CSVSink: Exports
> metrics data to CSV files at regular intervals. JmxSink: Registers
> metrics for viewing in a JMX console. MetricsServlet: Adds a servlet
> within the existing Spark UI to serve metrics data as JSON data.
> PrometheusServlet: (Experimental) Adds a servlet within the existing
> Spark UI to serve metrics data in Prometheus format. GraphiteSink:
> Sends metrics to a Graphite node. Slf4jSink: Sends metrics to slf4j as
> log entries. StatsdSink: Sends metrics to a StatsD node.

But wait... there's more.

You don't like this monitoring package?

You can plugin [your own monitoring](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/better-spark-logging-and-monitoring-with-spark-listener-c2c5fe86547a)